# node exec awk command quotations

Tags: node.js

Using this pattern to pass a parameter in exec command:

```
const the_xml_file = 'pubmed22n1171.xml';
const the_command = "echo " + the_xml_file;

async function myBash() {
    try {

        const { stdout, stderr } = await exec( the_command );

        console.log(stdout);

    } catch (err){
       console.error(err);
        //console.log('stderr:', stderr);
    };
  };
```

However when the command is

```
const the_command = "awk 'BEGIN{splitno=15000; sn=splitno+1; out=FILENAME\"_\"int(c++/sn)+1\".xml\"} /<PubmedArticle/{f=1} f{print > out} /<\/PubmedArticle>/&&c%sn==0{close(out); f=0}' " + the_xml_file;
```

I get an error:

```
Error: Command failed: awk 'BEGIN{splitno=15000; sn=splitno+1; out=FILENAME"_"int(c++/sn)+1".xml"} /<PubmedArticle/{f=1} f{print > out} /</PubmedArticle>/&&c%sn==0{close(out); f=0}' pubmed22n1171.xml
awk: non-terminated regular expression &&c%sn==0{... at source line 1
 context is
        BEGIN{splitno=15000; sn=splitno+1; out=FILENAME"_"int(c++/sn)+1".xml"} /<PubmedArticle/{f=1} f{print > out} /</PubmedArticle>/&&c%sn==0{close(out); >>>  f=0} <<<
```

Ive tested the awk command and it works from the console so I'm assuming this is a quotation mark issue. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: When you enter that command to a bourne/korn-type _shell_ (regardless if it's on a console or not) the part of the string `/<\/PubmedArticle/` is passed to awk with the `\/` intact and awk parse the slash as part of the regexp as intended, but when you put that string in javascript _that_ interprets the backslash and only passes `/</PubmedArticle/` which causes awk to treat the slash as terminating the regexp, and the last slash to start a new one. **Use _two_ backslashes `/<\\/PubmedArticle/`**